# How can I get a unique random output without getting the same element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to coding and this platform, so please forgive any mistakes I make. I've embarked on an automation project using Selenium with the goal of filling out a Google Form multiple times accurately.

In my script, I'm gathering XPaths for the form elements and using the random.choices function with weights to select which elements to interact with. However, I've encountered a challenge with multiple-choice questions. When a user can select multiple options as answers, I need to click on multiple elements without clicking on the same one twice.

The reason for this is that if the same XPath is clicked more than once, the click function will execute multiple times, potentially deselecting a previously chosen answer. To address this issue and ensure the accuracy of my automation, I'm looking for a solution to generate multiple unique XPaths for each answer option. I have included the code for the function.

```
class Multiple_Choice_Questions_Blueprint:

    def __init__(self, Choice_List, Xpath_Links_List, Weight_List, Choice_weight_list):

        self.Choice_List = Choice_List
        self.Xpath_Links_List = Xpath_Links_List
        self.Weight_List = Weight_List
        self.Choice_weight_List = Choice_weight_list
        
        Chosen_Numbers = random.choices(Choice_List, weights=Choice_weight_list)
        Chosen_Number = int(Chosen_Numbers[0])
        
        if (Chosen_Number == 1):
            self.Links = random.choices(Xpath_Links_List, weights=Weight_List)
            self.Link = self.Links[0]
            Get_option_id = driver.find_element("xpath", self.Link)
            Get_option_id.click()

        elif (Chosen_Number == 2):
            for i in range(2):
                self.Links = random.choices(Xpath_Links_List, weights=Weight_List)
                self.Link = self.Links[0]
                Get_option_id = driver.find_element("xpath", self.Link)
                Get_option_id.click()
        
        elif (Chosen_Number == 3):
            for i in range(3):
                self.Links = random.choices(Xpath_Links_List, weights=Weight_List)
                self.Link = self.Links[0]
                Get_option_id = driver.find_element("xpath", self.Link)
                Get_option_id.click()

        elif (Chosen_Number == 4):
            for i in range(4):
                self.Links = random.choices(Xpath_Links_List, weights=Weight_List)
                self.Link = self.Links[0]
                Get_option_id = driver.find_element("xpath", self.Link)
                Get_option_id.click()
        
        else:
            for i in range(random.randint(1,6)):
                self.Links = random.choices(Xpath_Links_List, weights=Weight_List)
                self.Link = self.Links[0]
                Get_option_id = driver.find_element("xpath", self.Link)
                Get_option_id.click()
```

I aimed to select multiple answers, but the tool ended up de clicking the previous answers. Which will remove the compulsory answer.

Comment: You could call `random.choices()` several times an zero out the weight of elements you already drew. Bit of manual work but should do the trick.